# Type conflict within DELETE itab1 FROM itab2?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I've had a dump recently,

```
DATA: gt_data    TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_data WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY bukrs gaapnm,
     ...
     lt_tabdel  TYPE standard TABLE OF ty_data.

  LOOP AT gt_data ASSIGNING <gf_data>.
    IF <gf_data>-KANSW + <gf_data>-KAUFW = 0.
      APPEND <gf_data> TO lt_tabdel.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

  IF lt_tabdel IS NOT INITIAL.
    DELETE gt_data FROM lt_tabdel.
  ENDIF.
```

And on the line with deleting table from internal table - i've had a dump: In statement
Convert object to integer
only numerical type data objects are supported at argument position
"object".
In the present case, operand "object" has the non-numerical data type "TABLE
 OF TY_DATA". I just can't understand - why? Both of it had the same type... So, it will be great if you could provide some advice and a bit of explanation of error origins.

Answer (score 5):

You have (inadvertently) used [this variant of the `DELETE` statement](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abapdelete_itab_lines.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@) that uses `FROM` and `TO` to specify indexes, i. e. numbers of table lines. In a sense, you are coding *delete all lines in `gt_data` below the one identified by the line number in `lt_tabdel`*, and the system goes belly-up when trying to convert the contents of `lt_tabdel` to an integer.

As far as I can see - i. E. if you've provided a complete code sample - this should be sufficient:

```
LOOP AT gt_data ASSIGNING <gf_data>.
  IF <gf_data>-KANSW + <gf_data>-KAUFW = 0.
    DELETE gt_data.
    CONTINUE. " safety measure
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

For an explanation of the `CONTINUE` statement, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632663/218890).

Comment: And if i want to delete all content from the table, that presented in another one, what should i use in that case?

Comment: Why are you using a separate loop in the first place?

Comment: May be there's need in new checks arises, and i suppose that existing table is too large to delete rows within loop. So, to evade additional load on servers - i prefer to fill additional table and delete it from previous main table later. So, separate loop was just a first idea that i had in mind. If there's a better way to do it - i'm all in.

Comment: You're not making sense there. If you need to remove the line, delete it. If you need multiple conditions, implement them.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF lt_tabdel IS NOT INITIAL.
DELETE gt_data FROM lt_tabdel.
ENDIF.

* IF lt_tabdel IS NOT INITIAL.
DELETE TABLE gt_data FROM lt_tabdel.
ENDIF. *
```

Adding TABLE will help you.

Comment: Please add more description to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i found solution. Delete - was the wrong command. So i used this one instead:

```
LOOP AT gt_data ASSIGNING <gf_data>.
    IF <gf_data>-KANSW + <gf_data>-KAUFW <> 0.
      append <gf_data> to lt_data.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

  gt_data[] = lt_data[].
```

Just filled another table and assigned it contents to the main table.

Comment: ...potentially doubling the runtime and memory requirements. Nice. *slowclap*

Comment: Uhm, just couldn't find another way. If you could provide some advise - i'll would appreciate it.