# Loop at internal table and delete a row in the internal table using a if statement

Tags: abap

I have my internal table `it_mseg`. In this table, there is a field called `amnt`.

I want to check for each row in `it_mseg`, if the field `amnt` is greater equal 10. If it is, I want to delete it from the internal table.

So that at the end, when I display the table using ALV-Grid, only the rows where the value of the field `amnt` is lower equal 10 will be displayed.

I know that this is somehow done with `Loop at it_mseg`, but I just can't get it right.

EDIT: I want to do it with a loop, so I can do something more complex than just GE 10.

Comment: [ABAP documentation: Processing Statements for Internal Tables](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_processing_statements.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete the current row from an internal table in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632238/delete-the-current-row-from-an-internal-table-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with LOOP, but even simplier with DELETE:

```
DELETE it_mseg WHERE amnt GT 10.
```

If you still want to do it with LOOP (because you want to check/change something else in the internal table):

```
LOOP AT it_mseg
     ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_mseg>).
  DATA(lv_tabix) = sy-tabix. "save sy-tabix for later use
... "do somthing else
  IF <ls_mseg>-amnt GT 10.
    DELETE it_mseg INDEX lv_tabix.
  ENDIF.
... "do something else
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Hmm yes, but how could I do it with loop? In case I want to do something a bit more complex than just  GT 10.

Comment: Then I suggest you to add that information in the question post, because Jozsef's answer hits the nail for the requirements you've put there.

Comment: @Lucky: I added that to my answer. If you want to have more complex condition, than "GT 10" than you have to modify it accordingly.

Comment: `DELETE it_mseg` behaves the same as `DELETE it_mseg INDEX lv_tabix`, but now you can remove the lv_tabix definition and have less places for errors

Comment: DELETE it_mseg is the best approach rather than use a use a LOOP. I personally think that deleting elements from an internal table that I'm looping is not ok.

Comment: @NelsonMiranda, why? It is about the same speed, and everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: @András Because when doing that, the indexes are regenerated affecting the performance. In my opinion, in this case, is better to use DELETE it_mseg.